# C# LINQ to Excel can't read decimals

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, linq-to-excel

I have a column where numbers are decimals in format ##,# with comma as delimiter. LINQ to Excel library reads them as 0.
[Excel file](https://prntscr.com/gvknjq).

Model property:

```
[ExcelColumn("Хим. добавки1")]
public decimal Chemical1 { get; set; }
```

My code:

```
var data = from a in file.WorksheetRange<Import>("A2", "U10000", "Учет производства").select a;
var datalist = data.Take(data.Count() - 1).ToList();
```

[What did I get](http://prntscr.com/gvkqen)

P.S. sorry, I can't open imgur.

**EDIT:** 
Excel columns corresponding to Model properties

- K column - Sheben1
- L column - Pesok1
- M column - Pesok2
- N column - Sheben2
- O column - Cement1
- P column - Cement2
- Q column - Chemical1
- R column - Chemical2
- S column - Water1
- T column - Water2
- U column - Water3

Comment: None of the numbers in your what you did get correspond with the numbers on your spreadsheet - so its very hard for us to follow for sure whats gone on.

Comment: BugFinder, There is only one column with decimals and it's Q column in Excel and Chemical1 in Model

Comment: No but the minimal viable demonstration is missing here - the "what did I get" shows numbers that bear no relation to whats shown in your spreadsheet.

Comment: "what did i get" shows number for the first row in Excel, I think that's enough to understand that Q column has "20,2" but first row of model after parsing doesn't have Chemical1 as it corresponds to Excel column via attribute

Comment: But the first numbers dont match up with the numbers in your screen shot!

Comment: I would suggest editing the question (avoiding the screenshots imgurl or prntscr) and adding a [mcve]. Building a minimal example sometimes you can find out the problem cause.

Comment: BugFinder, added information how excel corresponding to model

Comment: Just to confirm are the items in column Q that are integers (eg the 21) coming through correctly? ie it is definitely a problem with those entries with commas rather than an issue that column Q isn't being read in at all (just thinking if there is some kind of typo in the column name or similar)

Comment: Chris, thanks. I find that library couldn't read the column name "Хим. добавки1". Just renamed it and now it works, but why? Does linq-to-excel can't read dot in the name?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the “.” when you try to map your columns, linqtoexcel uses OleDb which changes “.” to “#” so if you don’t want to change the column in excel, just put “#” instead of “.” when mapping the columns

so using your code as an example

Change this:

```
[ExcelColumn("Хим. добавки1")]
public decimal Chemical1 { get; set; }
```

to this:

```
[ExcelColumn("Хим# добавки1")]
public decimal Chemical1 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Also, I realize this is a really late answer but better late than never